# wget recursive for only files that pass a regexp

Tags: wget

I would like to use wget recursively on an ftp directory like this:

ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/

Which contains another 2 directory levels inside, the first with the species name, and one inside with the name `dna`, like this:
ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/species_name/dna/

For example, one of them has the species_name `homo_sapiens`:

ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/homo_sapiens/dna/

Inside each `./dna/` directory, I would like to download only the file with the name containing the word `toplevel` but not the one containing the word `_rm.toplevel`.

Finally, I would like a wget recursive command that would download all those from these directories, each as an output file with the name `species_name.fa.gz`, where the `species_name` is the name of the parent directory, just before `dna`.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=331613

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `lftp`:

```
echo 'mirror --no-empty-dirs -I *toplevel* -X *_rm.toplevel* . .' | 
lftp ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/
for folder in *; do
  mv $folder/dna/*toplevel* $folder.fa.gz
  rm -r "$folder"
done
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I only change the renaming loop for a find/awk combo like this ($8 counts number of dirs):  find `pwd` -name "*.gz" | sort | grep toplevel | awk -F\/ '{print "mv "$i" "$8".fa.gz"}' > name.sh && bash ./name.sh

Answer (score 8):

You can tell wget to include or exclude files and directories based on wildcard patterns. Untested:

```
wget -R \
  -X '/*/?*dna,/*/pep' \
  -A '*toplevel*' -R '*_rm.toplevel*' \
  ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/
```

For FTP, wget isn't the best tool for complex retrieval. Wget knows how to follow links in a web page, but that's not relevant for FTP. I recommend mounting the FTP site as a directory with [AVFS](http://avfs.sourceforge.net/), [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) or some other [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem, and using `cp` or `rsync`. With AVFS:

```
mountavfs
ls ~/.avfs/\#ftp:ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/homo_sapiens
```

With CurlFtpFS:

```
mkdir ~/current_fasta
curlftpfs ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/ ~/current_fasta
ls ~/current_fasta/homo_sapiens
```

To copy the files in any shell:

```
for x in ~/.avfs/\#ftp:ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/*/dna/*toplevel*; do
  case $x in *_rm.toplevel*) continue;; esac
  species=${x%/dna/*}; species=${species##*/}
  cp -p "$x" "$species.fa.gz"
done
```

Or in zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -C '~/.avfs/\#ftp:ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/(*)/dna/*toplevel*~*_rm.toplevel*' '$1.fa.gz'
```